# What are the valid data types for vertex arrays in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

What are the valid data types for vertex arrays in WebGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid data types for vertex arrays in WebGL are:<sup>1</sup>

1. byte,
2. ubyte,
3. short,
4. ushort,
5. float

The corresponding constants are:

1. BYTE,
2. UNSIGNED_BYTE,
3. SHORT,
4. UNSIGNED_SHORT,
5. FLOAT

Note that while you can send these data types to the GPU, you can only use the attribute storage qualifier in your shader program with variables that are either type float, vec2, vec3, vec4, mat2, mat3, or mat4.<sup>2</sup>

Also note that as opposed to OpenGL ES 2.0, WebGL does not support the fixed data type.<sup>3</sup>

Sources:

1. Table 2.4 on p. 20 of the [OpenGL ES 2.0.25 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) applicable through Section 1.1 of the [WebGL 1.0 spec.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/)
2. Section 4.3.3 of the [GLSL ES 1.0.17 spec.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) applicable through Section 4.3 of the WebGL 1.0 spec.
3. Section 6.14 of the WebGL 1.0 spec.